# Is checking for wp_next_scheduled() necessary before calling wp_schedule_event()? If so, why?

Tags: wordpress

Almost every wp_schedule_event tutorial goes something like this:

```
function my_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_hourly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

(from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#Examples)

If you wouldn't do the check, will the event not get scheduled, or "scheduled again" or what?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checking if an event has already been scheduled before running `wp_schedule_event` is a precaution.

The scheduling of an event normally takes place upon plugin activation. There's usually also a deactivation hook to unschedule the event.

The problem arises when an existing event isn't cleared properly. There are many reasons that an event might not be cleared such as the user manually deleting the plugin or an error upon deactivation.

Re-activating the plugin would add the same event again with a different timestamp resulting in the callback executing more frequently than anticipated.